# Differentiability around a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is continuously differentiable at a point $a$ and $f'(a)\neq 0$ then why will $f$ be diiferentiable at neighbourhood around $a$?

Any help in understanding why it happens will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a function is continuously differentiable at a point?

Comment: "Continuously differentiable" means that the derivative is continuous, so the derivative is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes correct. Thanks.